# socket is terminating for some reason

Tags: python, sockets

so I am a newbie in python and I am trying to establish a server-client program in python, but I want when I send something from server or the client, the other side has to listen till the sender finish his message, so I made a function called `recvTillTimeOut` which is supposed to receive till timeout occurs and this is the body of the function:

```
def recvTillTimeOut(s):
    s.settimeout(1)
    data = b''
    while True:
         try:
            data += s.recv(1024)
            print(data)
         except:
            print("error")
            break
    return data
```

but every time, the console outputs that there is an exception in this function after the connection is established between the server and the client, so I don't know what did I do wrong.

---

### server code

```
import socket
# package needed in serializing and deserializing data
import pickle

# this is a function to receive till timeout occurs
def recvTillTimeOut(s):
    s.settimeout(1)
    data = b''
    while True:
         try:
            data += s.recv(1024)
            print(data)
         except:
            print("error")
            break
    return data

# this is the least number of bits needed for encryption/decryption to be done correctly

# generating both public and private keys
PublicKey = [2342314, 422421]

# Creating a socket
mySocket = socket.socket()

# getting hostname
host = socket.gethostname()

# the port that communication will happen through
portNum = 12345

# the port isn't created yet, as I am a server
mySocket.bind((host, portNum))

# make at most 2 clients to be served simultaneously
mySocket.listen(2)

# accept a connection
clientConn, clientAddr = mySocket.accept()

try:

    # receive public key of the client and deserialize IT
    data = recvTillTimeOut(mySocket)
    clientkey = pickle.loads(data)

    print(clientkey)

    # serialize the public key and send it
    data = pickle.dumps(PublicKey)
    mySocket.send(data)

    while True:

        # receiving data from the client
        data = clientConn.recv(1024).decode()

        if not data:
            # if the connection is closed then end the program
            break

        # printing the received message
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))

        # send response to the client
        data = input(" -> ")
        clientConn.send(data.encode())

except:
    # close the socket
    mySocket.close()


# close the socket
mySocket.close()
```

---

### Client code

```
import socket
import pickle

# this is a function to receive till timeout occurs
def recvTillTimeOut(s):
    s.settimeout(1)
    data = b''
    while True:
         try:
            data += s.recv(1024)
         except:
            break
    return data



# generating both public and private keys
PublicKey = [100123120, 5124210]

# getting hostname
host = socket.gethostname()

# the port that communication will happen through
portNum = 12345

# Creating a socket
mySocket = socket.socket()

# connect to the server
mySocket.connect((host, portNum))

try:

    # serialize the public key and send it
    data = pickle.dumps(PublicKey)
    mySocket.send(data)

    # receive public key of the server and deserialize IT
    data = recvTillTimeOut(mySocket)
    serverkey = pickle.loads(data)

    print(serverkey)


    # the port is already open, so I am a client
    while True:

        # take input from the user
        message = input(" -> ")

        # end the connection
        if message == 'bye':
            break

        # send message to the server
        mySocket.send(message.encode())

        # receive data from the server
        data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

        print('Received from server: ' + data)

except:
    # close the socket
    mySocket.close()

# close the socket
mySocket.close()
```

Comment: What's the name of the exception you get?

Comment: @user3435121, the exception is `timed out` for both server and client

Comment: This should teach you to never use a blanket `except`

Answer (score 0):

so, I found what I did wrong here, in Server Coder, instead of :

```
recvTillTimeOut(mySocket)
```

I should have written :

```
recvTillTimeOut(clientConn)
```

and I changed the way I receive and send data (I suppose I shouldn't wait till timeout occur so that I know the data is fully sent)

so I changed the function `recvTillTimeOut` from this implementation :

```
# this is a function to receive till timeout occurs
def recvTillTimeOut(s):
    s.settimeout(1)
    data = b''
    while True:
         try:
            data += s.recv(1024)
         except:
            break
    return data
```

to this implementation:

```
def recvData(s):
    #receive length of data first
    dataLen = struct.unpack('>I', s.recv(4))[0]
    data = s.recv(dataLen)
    return data
```

where I first send the length of the data then the actual data, so the lines of codes to send data is actually like this:

```
    PublicKey = [2342314, 422421]
    # serialize the public key and send it
    data = pickle.dumps(PublicKey)
    clientConn.send(struct.pack('>I', len(data)))
    clientConn.send(data)
```

and the codes of receiving is actually like this:

```
    # receive public key of the client and deserialize IT
    data = recvData(clientConn)
    clientkey = pickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: `recv` can receive less than `datalen`.  Check return value, e.g. if `recv(10)` and get 6, then `recv(4)` and check again.  Also `send` can send less than requested.  Use `sendall`.  May appear to work otherwise until under network load.